Python.exe file not found?
I just simply installed Python 3.10, and I have tried running the repair client, uninstalling, and reinstalling multiple times.
PS C:\Users\name> cd folder
PS C:\Users\name\folder> pip install -r requirements.txt
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"C:\Python310\python.exe"  "C:\Python310\Scripts\pip.exe" install -r requirements.txt': The system cannot find the file specified.

PS C:\Users\name\folder>


Since you are using windows, the problem is highly likey your Environment Variables
https://www.mygreatlearning.com/blog/add-python-to-path/
Although I would like to suggest using Pyenv instead of directly installing python, because it is easier to manage multiple python versions in your machine
